# Can I put a button inside an option of a dataList on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

With the following code:

I would want to include a button next to the option to delete this option. I´m working with angularJS.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: <datalist id="previousSearches">
                                <option ng-repeat="search in savedSearches" value="{{search}}" ng-model="adressSelected"> 
                            </datalist>